# Where is the default location of trace log and what would be the file name

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

I inherited some old codes - Winform and with click once deployment. Trace log is what confuses me. This is what I see in configuration file. Where ( folder and file name) should I look for trace data ?

```
              <listeners>
              <add name="FileLog"/>
            </listeners>

    <sharedListeners>
          <add name="FileLog" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.Logging.FileLogTraceListener, 
Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=8.0.0.0, 
initializeData="FileLogWriter"/>
        </sharedListeners>
```

Comment: Found it: There was a customized trace listener class. That file was writing data.